# Ionic2 Storage Promise.all scope

Tags: angular, typescript, scope, ionic2, storage

does anyone know how to assign an Ionic2 Storage.get value to my local variable? If I console.log inside the .then, works fine, but it seems to only exist inside that function/method. 
Most examples I see, show how to 'get' my data but no really apply it to my other code

-thanks

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {

favDessertMax: string;
favDessertRuby: string;

constructor(storage: Storage) { }

 storage.ready().then(() => {

   this.storage.set('Max', 'Apple sauce');
   this.storage.set('Ruby', 'Banana split');


   Promise.all([
       this.storage.get('Max'),
       this.storage.get('Ruby'),
   ])
     .then(([val1,val2]) => {
       this.favDessertMax = val1; 
       this.favDessertRuby = val1;
       console.log(val1 + " " + val2); //values work here
     })
   console.log(val1 + " " + val2); // values don't work out here (or anywhere else)
   });

  storyTime() { // Need value to work here
    let myStory = 'Max likes ' + this.favDessertMax + ' and Ruby Likes 'this.favDessertRuby';
  return myStory;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.all` is setting data to your local variable. It is asynchronous so you may not get the data *when* you call `storyTime()`.
You will have to chain the promise to make sure you will get the data.

```
getData(){

    return Promise.all([
           this.storage.get('Max'),
           this.storage.get('Ruby'),
       ])
         .then(([val1,val2]) => {
           this.favDessertMax = val1;  // from 'Max'
           this.favDessertRuby = val2; // from 'Ruby'
           return [val1,val2];//return value in then.
           console.log(val1 + " " + val2); //values work here
         })
       });
    }

storyTime() { // Need value to work here
    return this.getData().then([val1,val2]=>{
    let myStory = 'Max likes ' + val1 + ' and Ruby Likes '+ val2 + ';
    return myStory;
     });
  }
```